# VirtualBox USB Tablet not recognized in Ubuntu 12.04.4

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, touchpad

My touchpad is not recognized in Ubuntu 12.04.4 running in VirtualBox 4.2.16. It is working fine in Ubuntu 14.04.

Is there some trick to get this working? I am really missing the two finger scroll feature.

Many Thanks...

Answer (score 1):

In case this helps, it is working now after a reinstall. It might have been either upgrading VirtualBox to 4.3.10 or installation of the Guest additions.